# how do I retrieve the latest telegram bot messages posted in a channel through the api?

Tags: telegram-bot

I want to see the last post a bot makes to my channel through the API/https
I tried getUpdates and it only shows messages I sent to the bot.  I'd like to see messages the bot broadcasts to my channel

https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/getUpdates

Answer (score 0):

The `getUpdates` method only retrieves messages that are sent to the bot by normal users. Bots **cannot** see other bot messages, that means it cannot see its own messages. However you can track messages sent by the bot in your code logic. E.g. in Node.js you would do something like:

```js
bot.sendMessage(channelId, "The message sent to the channel").then(ctx => {
    // ctx contains the details of the message sent to the channel
    // you can do whatever you want with it
});
```